# laravel form not directing as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a registration in laravel.

I am expecting this form on submit to take me to (the same page I am on) http://localhost:8888/mylaravel/notetomyself/public/auth/register

but on submitting it actually ends up at http://localhost:8888/auth/register

The following code is my view in views/auth/register.blade.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/auth/register">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Register
</button>
</div>

</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

my routes.php file contains this:

```
Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showLogin'));
Route::get('home', array('uses' => 'Home@index'));
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));
Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogout'));
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::controllers([
   'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

The controller auth/AuthController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    private $redirectTo = '/';
    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Wondering if there is somewhere I might have set the wrong paths?

Comment: Have you changed the `Authenticate.php` & `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you are redirected there :**

Its because you form action points to `/auth/register` [As it is without full path web server simply treats as your domain name as root path].

**What you should do  :**

Simply remove the `/` before `auth` in `action="/auth/register"`

**Additional Tip :** (To do after fix)

To handle the redirection after/before authentication you should customize according to your change in `Authenticate.php` and `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` inside `app/Http/Middleware` either by `return redirect()->guest('yourpath');` or to let in the request `return $next($request);`

**Note :**

Change the action according to your routes !

Comment: I removed the "/" still does the same thing

Comment: Have you cleared the views and tried in incognito mode ?

Comment: okay in incognito mode I got the error "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:"

Comment: Yes you are on right path, inside storage/framework/views delete all files

Comment: Have you wrote routes for auth ?

Comment: This isn't working because if he is on `example.com/auth/register`, the relative URL will take him to `example.com/auth/auth/register`.

Comment: @ThomasKim Yeah its true , i guess the op will change the action accordingly :) Update in answer too Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, your path is relative to the root domain. The simplest solution is to use Laravel's URL helper functions to create an absolute URL. You have several options.

1. Generate an absolute URL to the given path:

   ```
   action="{{ url('auth/register') }}"
   ```
2. Generate an absolute URL using a route name

   ```
   action="{{ route('routeName') }}"
   ```
3. Generate an absolute URL specifying a controller action:

   ```
   action="{{ action('Auth\AuthController@postRegister') }}"
   ```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls